# Practical Understanding of Log a / Log b Running Time

Tags: complexity

Was wondering if someone could give a practical understanding of what it means for an algorithm to perform in (log a / log b) time?

In other words, practically speaking for an algorithm to perform in nlogn time it would need to split a max of log n times and perform n amount of work at each level. For log n performance it would split a max of log n times and perform at most a constant amount of work at each level, etc.

What would be the equivalent way of explaining the performance of a log a / log b algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: An algorithm with two size metrics: `a` and `b` which executes in time proportional to the graph of `log a / log b`. It would take about a time unit when `a` and `b` are similarly sized. When `b` is much larger than `a` then it will execute faster, when `a` is much larger than `b` it will execute slower. the scale is logarithmic so as the values of `a` and `b` get larger total execution time becomes more stable, simply adding 1 to either will have little effect. however when `a` and `b` are smaller adding 1 will be much more noticeable.

Comment: Care to notice that `log a / log b` equals `log a base b`. When we talk about logaritmic  complexities, we usualy mean log base 2 which comes from binary nature of computer data representations. Now imagine merge sort algo which instead of bisecting, trisects. Its complexity would be n*log n base 3 which Is n*log n / log 3.

Comment: In other words, imagine your description of `log n` but instead of the word "Split" use word "bisect". And Now change the word to "b-sect" And you got yourself a description of log n / log b.